# I can't install ubuntu on my asus s451l

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have a new computer and unfortunately it came with an operating system called windows. I want to install ubuntu on it but I have falied epicly, apparently it has something to do with UEFI. I already disabled fastboot and secure boot. I think I have to manually tell UEFI to prioritize the CD-DVD boot in UEFI but there is no such option. UEFI allows me to "create a new boot option" but I have no idea how to create one that reads my ubuntu install disk. I have also tried to install it via a USB but it doesn't work, I have no idea how I can get it to install.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i had a problem very close to what your experiencing with my Asus X511ma. i was scratching my head over for days trying to figure out why i cant install any linux on my computer accept for arch-linux. then just by a fluke when i had pretty much lost hope for my computer, i updated my bios by downloading a new firmware and put it in a usb flash-drive. with the flash-utility option inside bios i updated and now get alot more options in bios. and could then change the OS Selection from 8.x to windows 7 and some other boot configuration. This solved my problem i can now install whatever linux i want. :D Hope this helpes somebody.